Expo project is not loading No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - expo project running eas build in real device via expo
  export default {
  expo: {
    name: 'trainingandfitness',
    slug: 'trainingandfitness',
    version: '1.0.0',
    orientation: 'portrait',
    icon: './assets/kacl.png',
    scheme: 'myapp',
    entryPoint: './App.tsx',
    userInterfaceStyle: 'automatic',
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    // splash: {
    //   image: "./assets/images/splash.png",
    //   resizeMode: "contain",
    //   backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    // },
    plugins: [
      '@react-native-firebase/app',
      '@react-native-firebase/auth',
      '@react-native-firebase/firestore',
      '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin',
      [
        'expo-build-properties',
        {
          ios: {
            useFrameworks: 'static',
          },
        },
      ],
      [
        'expo-document-picker',
        {
          iCloudContainerEnvironment: 'Production',
        },
      ],
    ],
    ios: {
      googleServicesFile: process.env.GOOGLE_SERVICES_PLIST,
      supportsTablet: true,
      bundleIdentifier: 'com.josh.training-and-fitnesse',
    },
    android: {
      googleServicesFile: process.env.GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON,
      adaptiveIcon: {
        foregroundImage: './assets/adaptive-icon.png',
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
      },
      package: 'com.josh.training_and_fitness',
    },
    web: {
      bundler: 'metro',
      output: 'static',
      favicon: './assets/kacl.png',
    },
    plugins: ['expo-router'],
    experiments: {
      typedRoutes: true,
    },
    extra: {
      router: {
        origin: false,
      },
      eas: {
        projectId: '0963b81c-4574-4a79-a96b-6f0ce03a48eb',
      },
    },
    owner: 'sudhansu888',
  },
}


above is the app.config.json file. One more thing i am not using
since i include service.json and plist files My package json looks like
"dependencies": {
   "@dev-plugins/react-query": "^0.0.7",
    "@expo/config": "~9.0.0",
    "@expo/metro-config": "~0.18.1",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^4.4.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^20.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^20.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^20.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/functions": "^20.5.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^12.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.20",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.26",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.29",
    "@shopify/flash-list": "1.6.4",
    "@shopify/react-native-skia": "1.2.3",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.40.0",
    "d3": "^7.9.0",
    "expo": "~51.0.8",
    "expo-application": "~5.9.1",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.12.1",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.18",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.5",
    "expo-keep-awake": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.14",
    "expo-secure-store": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.4",
    "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lottie-react-native": "6.7.0",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.1",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-simple-line-chart": "^0.34.4",
    "react-native-svg": "15.2.0",
    "react-native-ui-datepicker": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10"
  }


Unable to run app on android device using eas build in expo app
I am using eas build and running on real device. I have rebuild the project couple of time. All the service json file is correctly referenced and
